# Does Hinduism also have the Creation Story?

Tags: belief, brahma, creation

Some major religions like Christianity, Islam and Judaism have the **Creation Story**, which describes how God created the universe, the earth and then the first man and woman, who are regarded as the father and mother of all mankind.

Does Hinduism also have the Creation Story?

Comment: There are many versions of the creation story according many traditions/philosophies. But the creation story isn't as essential as it is in Christianity or Judaism.

Comment: Since Hinduism don't have a birth date, compare the answers to this questions with the stories exists in Christianity or Judaism. Look how they modified and used them.

Answer (score 11):

Hinduism doesn't have **a creation story**, it has **a lots of creation stories**. Creation stories are central to *[puranas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranas)*, local myths and beliefs. So there are a lot of variations to the stories even between *purana* to *purana*. But regarding the concept of first man and woman, yes it's also there in Hinduism. They are known as [Manu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manu_(Hinduism)) and Shatarupa.

However, the creation stories are not exactly like that of the other religions where God created the world and the first man and woman just appeared inside it in the sixth day or so. In most of the *puranas* the creation process starts from [Vishnu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu), from whom arises [Brahma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma) and then Brahma creates all other beings. Among all the beings that are created, not all were of the same type. Some were gods, some were demons, some were sages and so on. So Manu was one of the created beings who propagated the human lineage on earth. He even built a boat during a great flood to preserve life on earth. You will find this similar to Noah's ark story.

But apart from the stories, scriptures also maintain statements in favour of evolutionary process of creation. For example, the Taitariya Upanishad says:

> *tasmādvā etasmādātmana ākāśaḥ saṃbhūtaḥ ākāśādvāyuḥ vāayoragniḥ agnerāpaḥ  adabhyaḥ pṛthivī  pṛthivyā oṣadhayaḥ oṣadhībhyonnam annātpuruṣaḥ* [Tait. Up. - 2.1]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Verily from this Self (the singularity) arose the space; from space air, from air fire, from fire water, from water earth, from earth minerals, from minerals vegetation and from vegetation man.

So because Hinduism doesn't have only one authoritative book, there is no single authoritative creation story. And because creation stories are part of mythology they tend to vary from scripture to scripture at least to some extent.

**Reference:**
[Shrimad Bhagavatam, 2.5](http://vedabase.com/en/sb/2/5)
[Shrimad Bhagavatam, 2.6](http://vedabase.com/en/sb/2/6)

Answer (score 5):

*Creation Story* of the universe can be described as a Big Loop which include many nested loop systems. Will start with a loop that actually describes how **Earth** and **Creatures** created.

**Brahma** as all know is **Shrushtikarta**, means he have the ultimate power to creation. The time of **Brahma** will start after a **Brahma Kalpa**. **Brahma Kalpa** is like replacement of **Brahma**. When new person take charge as **Bramha** he will *pray* *Lord Vishnu* to give powers to make creations. *Lord Vishnu* will give powers to **Brahma** to create universe.

Initial stage of the universe will be in the shape of **Golden Egg** this *Egg* is created by **Bramha**, so **Bramha** is also called as **Hiranyagarbha**. This *Egg* will split into two parts, top half will become 7 *Oordhvalokas* and below part becomes 7 *Adharalokas*. This completes first stage of **Srushti**.

Then comes other creations. Since **Brahma** can't handle everything, he will create few assistants. First **Bramha** creates 4 sons *Sanaka, Sanatana, Sanandana* and *Sanatkumara*. But they refused to assist him in his creation process and proceed to be in *Bramhacharya* forever. Then **Bramha** creates 9 sons together they called *NavaBramha* and they are, *Marichi, Atri, Angirasa, Pulastya, Pulaha, Pratu, Bhrugu, Vasista* and *Daksha*. *Narada* is considered as *Bramha Manasa Putra* but will not take part in **Srushti**. Then these 9 sons of **Brahma** carried **Srushti**.

**Pratu** one among nine sons of **Brahma** had assigned with the task to find a suitable place for **Srushti**. He searched all locations to find a suitable planet. Then he choose planet *Earth* to continue **Srushti**. Because **Pratu** found this planet, so this planet is named accordingly **Pruthvi**.

This process will be continued only when **Brahma** will change. Between this change there will be again small **Srushti**. There is also a case where **Srushti** will happen only on earth. This will be at the end of all *Yugas*. There are different ways of ending to all creatures on this earth. This depends on how many times all 4 *Yugas* repeated. This small ending is called as *Pralaya*. In a normal case, *Jala Pralaya* will happen. In case of *Jala Pralaya*, *Markandeya Mahamuni* will prepare a big *Boat*, big enough to fit all life samples in it. Then he will collect all life samples in it and tie that boat to *Mainaka Parvata*. After the end of *Jala Pralaya*, he will start the **Srushti** again.

There is more to explain but less time. I have just mentioned basics of **Srushti**. You can find different explanation in different scripts. What I have given is from **Bhagavatam**. Still there is lot to explain, but I too have less info with me.

Comment: Hi Bharadwaj, maintain consistent spelling for Srushti. Also can you give reference from bhagavatam.

Comment: You forgot Shiva from whom Vishnu came as mentioned in Shiva Purana.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, whether I am overshooting the concept, but there is a very interesting observation you take from Dasavatharam ( the 10 avatars of God).

1. Matsya avatar  - Fish  ( Aquatic)
2. Kurma avatar  - Tortoise ( Amphibian)
3. Varaha avatar - Bear (Mammal)
4. Narasimha avatar - Half man, Half animal ( Early Neanderthal)
5. Vamana avatar - Short man ( First man, Short statured)
6. Parasurama avatar - Angry man ( Hunting for food, and killing from anger)
7. Rama avatar - Organized society man (Hunting for land, and food)
8. Krishna avatar - Love and kindness ( Advanced intelligence - revenge, love, kindness)
9. Buddha avatar - Advanced thoughts ( Peace, Harmony, higher order thoughts)
10. Kalki avatar - Self destructive thoughts ( Global warming, greed, exploitation)

Now, I dont want to say that the person who wrote it, had all these ideas in mind. But have a look again.. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashavatara

This was Charles Darwins theory written by Bhagavata Purana and Vishnu Purana around 200 BC to 20 BC.

Comment: What Dashavatar has to do with creation theory? Dashavatar came after the creation.

Comment: Many believe the Dashavatara story as a symbolic story of biological evolution