# What is the Hindu theory of creation?

Tags: belief, brahma, creation

Can someone please describe some of the theories of creation as per the Hindu ancient texts?

How about the origin of matter ? I seem to remember a reference to something akin to the Big Bang; when the sound of Omkar created the universe.

Comment: [possible duplicate] please look here: [Does Hinduism also have the Creation Story?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2099/2995)

Comment: makes sense. how about the theory on the origin of the universe?

Comment: In the beginning was the Word (AUM), the word was with God (Brahman). the Word was God (Ishvara). From the Word, the Universe was created :). Through the five elements came all of the universe. First was AUM, then from AUM came Akasha, Vayu, Agni, Apaha and Earth. Through permutations and combinations of the five elements the entire Universe was created. This is one of the theory of creation present and believed by Yogis, Vedantins and Hindus all sir