# What were the different theories of origin of Universe as per Matsya and Kurma Puranas?

Tags: puranas, creation, universe, cosmology

How was the Universe created according  to Matsya and Kurma Puranas?

Each Purana had it's  own theory for origin of Universe.
(Please cite references from the Puranas)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How was the universe created?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8508/how-was-the-universe-created)

Comment: Also see: [What is the source of creation according to Upanishads?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5230/21103) and [Does Hinduism also have the Creation Story?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2093/21103)

Comment: It partly answers but I do need the different theories  of  origin  of Universe  according  to the Puranas. The questions  you mentions  is mostly about the origin of Universe  according to  Upanishads and Bhagavad gita.

Comment: The answer will be too broad  for creation theory for all of 18 So  it's highly recommended to limit  the query for just one or two.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too broad to answer from all of the 18 purana the answer will be too long to read.

Comment: Voting to reopen as it is now specific to only two puranas.